# Change diagram to bottom up instead of left to right

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js

In below cluster diagram the clusters are flowing from left to right.

I would like the clusters to be displayed as "bottom up" like so :

[image]

Here is how the diagram is currently being displayed :

[image]

Here is the code that generates this diagram :

```
var width = 460,
    height = 500;

var cluster = d3.layout.cluster()
    .size([height, width - 160]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function (d) {
    return [d.y, d.x];
});

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(40,0)");

    var nodes = cluster.nodes(getData()),
        links = cluster.links(nodes);

    var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(links)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", diagonal);

    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    })

    node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 4.5);

    node.append("text")
        .attr("dx", function (d) { return d.children ? -8 : 8; })
        .attr("dy", 3)
        .style("text-anchor", function (d) { return d.children ? "end" : "start"; })
        .text(function (d) { return d.name; });

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");


function getData() {
    return {"children":[{"children":[{"name":"cluster","children":[{"name":"AgglomerativeCluster","size":3938},{"name":"TestCLuster","size":3938}]}],"name":"analytics"}],"name":"flare"}
}

.node circle {
    fill: #fff;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.node {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.link {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ccc;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

Here is a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/drW3e/25/

How the code be updated so that the diagram is displayed "bottom up" instead of "left to right" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit of playing around with it, swapping x & y values seems like a good start,

so

```
return [d.y, d.x];
```

would become

```
return [d.x, d.y];
```

etc...

http://jsfiddle.net/drW3e/27/

Comment: it seems "flare" is now overflowing the screen, as part of its icon is hidden. Can the diagram be pushed down to counteract this ?